# I am working on iCloud and I have confusion regarding NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey

Tags: ios, icloud

I read Apples doc and I got below information,
NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey
The value is an NSNumber object that contains a Boolean indicating whether the current version of the item has been downloaded and is available locally.

so now query is that suppose I have two devices iPhoneA and iPhoneB and there is one common file named file1, now suppose right now I have iCloud version of file1 on both devices so NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey will be 1 for file1 on both devices.

then I modify file1 on iPhoneB and have uploaded it on iCloud, so now when I run application on iPhoneA and start iCloud sync what will be value of NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey for file1.

Comment: Guys can you please help me with this query?

Comment: Have you actually tried doing it and seeing what the value is?

Comment: @Abizern Yes, I checked and received Value = 1 for DownloadedKey on iPhoneA

Comment: So that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey value will be 1 for this case.